# When would Rails' ActiveRecord generate IN clause with empty parentheses? "IN ()"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Assuming I call ActiveRecord model Foo like this:

```
Foo.sum(:bar, :conditions => { :baz_id => some_value })
```

When would that result in invalid SQL query with empty list in IN clause like below:

```
SELECT sum(`foos`.bar) AS sum_bar FROM `foos` WHERE (`foos`.baz_id IN ())
```

I am using activerecord 2.3.12.

Answer (score 1):

I can't check right now as I don't have application with Rails 2.3 running on my machine, but how about empty array? I think AR checks if what you provide is collection (array) and if so, then it generates "IN (...)" part, and then it generates entries for "IN" clause with proper escaping.

*EDIT*:

Empty array generates `(NULL)`, so it's valid. Array with empty array generates serialized YAML so it's not that case.

I checked in [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a2a34133d8347d83c015b1889a774c718644e4d6/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb) and it's possible to generate empty "IN ()" part, you just need to:

1. provide a parameter which is one of this: `Array`, `ActiveRecord::Associations::AssociationCollection`, `ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope`, [line 2031](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a2a34133d8347d83c015b1889a774c718644e4d6/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L2031)
2. it should `#respond_to?(:map)`, but should not `#acts_like?(:string)`, [line 2424](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a2a34133d8347d83c015b1889a774c718644e4d6/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L2424)
3. its `#empty?` should return false for some reason, or it should not `respond_to?(:empty?)`, [line 2425](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a2a34133d8347d83c015b1889a774c718644e4d6/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L2425)
4. it has to respond to `#map`, but should return empty array, [line  2428](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a2a34133d8347d83c015b1889a774c718644e4d6/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L2428)

And then it generates what you have.

I have no idea how it could happen in real code. Maybe there are other ways to create this case in real life code...

Comment: Wild guess... a *nested* empty array?

Answer (score 0):

Is that the SQL it generates (`IN ())`? In my test (AR 2.3.8), it issues a `IN (NULL)`, which works just fine.

Comment: Well, in my case it issues "IN ()" which is not fine. The question is what is `some_value` when that happens ;)

Comment: ok, I see, but can't you debug the point when this is happening and see the value of `some_value`? it's weird, the most logic value to do that is an empty array, but this has always worked for me...

Comment: Well, empty array is fine, as well as `nil`. I will debug it myself but this error is quite rare and I hoped that somebody might give answer more quickly.